# Monitor Synchronization: Implementing multiple condition variables

Tags: python, synchronization, operating-system, monitor

I am implementing monitor synchronization. I was wondering how does implementing multiple condition variables works.
So a condition variable has method wait() which puts it on the wait queue for a specific lock tied to this condition variable. So if I have multiple condition variables, do each wait call create its own separate wait queue?
For eg, if I have:

```
lock = Lock()  
A = Condition(lock)  
B = Condition(lock)  
C = Condition(lock)  

def foo:  
     with lock:  
        while true:  
            A.wait()  

def bar:  
    with lock:  
        while true:  
            B.wait()  

def notifyA  
    with lock:  
        A.notifyAll()
```

So my question is that when we do A.notifyAll(), does it only wake up stuff in the A.wait queue or this there a combined queue for associated with the lock.

Comment: implementing in what language?

Answer (score 2):

`A.notifyAll()` should only wake up the thread running `foo()`.  The wait queue your threads are `wait()`-ing in is part of the *condition variable*, not the *lock*.  The lock does have its own wait queue, but it's only used by threads trying to acquire the lock.  When your thread sleeps in a CV, it doesn't hold the lock, and won't try to reacquire it until another thread calls `notify()` or similar.

That said, you should write your code to assume that `B.wait()` could in fact wake up at any time.  Practically that means re-checking the condition the thread is waiting on:

```
    with lock:
        while not ready:
            B.wait()
        # Do stuff with protected data
```